# How do I configure Safari to show SVG locally?

Tags: safari, svg

I checked to see if there was something wrong with Safari in general when it comes to rendering SVG, but an SVG drawing on a website works just fine: http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml

My conclusion was that there is something about Safari that keeps me from rendering SVG elements locally. This is the code that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <circle r="50"></circle>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

What can I do so that the above SVG circle renders on Safari? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: It renders fine for me (Safari 5.1.7, OSX 10.7.4), although I only see the lower-right quadrant.

Comment: @ScottHunter Safari 5.0.5, OSX 10.6.8 - I don't see a thing! My version of Safari isn't ridiculously old enough for it to cease showing SVG. Or so I thought.

Answer (score 0):

create separate .svg file for you svg.

```
circle.svg

<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

     <circle r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

rewrite your HTML like this.

```
<body>
    <embed src="circle1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
</body>
```